# How to get an element index in a list column, if element is specified in a different column

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

I have a dataframe, where one column `a` is a list, and another column `b` contains a value that's in `a`. I need to create the column `c` which contains index of the element in `b` in list `a`

```
df = pl.DataFrame({'a': [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 2], [6, 2, 7]], 'b': [3, 4, 2]})
print(df)

shape: (3, 2)
┌───────────┬─────┐
│ a         ┆ b   │
│ ---       ┆ --- │
│ list[i64] ┆ i64 │
╞═══════════╪═════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] ┆ 3   │
│ [4, 5, 2] ┆ 4   │
│ [6, 2, 7] ┆ 2   │
└───────────┴─────┘
```

so resulting dataframe looks like following

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────┬─────┬────────────┐
│ a         ┆ b   ┆ a.index(b) │
│ ---       ┆ --- ┆ ---        │
│ list[i64] ┆ i64 ┆ i64        │
╞═══════════╪═════╪════════════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] ┆ 3   ┆ 2          │
│ [4, 5, 2] ┆ 4   ┆ 0          │
│ [6, 2, 7] ┆ 2   ┆ 1          │
└───────────┴─────┴────────────┘
```

all elements of `a` are unique within the row, and `b` is guaranteed to be in `a`.

Comment: yeah, from what i gather, apply with a custom python function is not efficient. so i'm looking for the solution using Expression API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to make two helper columns. one is just a copy of `a` and the other is the index values of `a`. We then explode by each of them and then filter for when `b`==`acopy`. Lastly, we clean it up by dropping our `acopy`

```
(
    df
        .with_columns(
            pl.col('a').alias('acopy'), 
            pl.arange(0,pl.col('a').arr.lengths()).alias("a.index(b)"))
        .explode(['acopy',"a.index(b)"])
        .filter(pl.col('acopy')==pl.col('b'))
        .drop('acopy')
)

shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────┬─────┬────────────┐
│ a         ┆ b   ┆ a.index(b) │
│ ---       ┆ --- ┆ ---        │
│ list[i64] ┆ i64 ┆ i64        │
╞═══════════╪═════╪════════════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] ┆ 3   ┆ 2          │
│ [4, 5, 2] ┆ 4   ┆ 0          │
│ [6, 2, 7] ┆ 2   ┆ 1          │
└───────────┴─────┴────────────┘
```

We can make this robust to dropping your guarantees about uniqueness (taking the first instance) and also allowing for the `b` value to not be in `a` while still returning the row with a null.

So, say we started with:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({'a': [[1, 2, 4], [4, 4, 2], [6, 2, 7]], 'b': [3, 4, 2]})
```

then we could do

```
(
    df
        .with_row_count('i')
        .with_columns(
            pl.col('a').alias('acopy'), 
            pl.arange(0,pl.col('a').arr.lengths()).alias("a.index(b)"))
        .explode(['acopy',"a.index(b)"])
        .with_columns(
            (pl.when(pl.col('acopy')==pl.col('b'))
                .then(pl.col("a.index(b)"))
                .otherwise(None)).alias("a.index(b)")
            )
        .groupby('i', maintain_order=True)
        .agg(
            pl.exclude('a.index(b)').first(),
            pl.col('a.index(b)').min())
        .drop(['i', 'acopy'])
)

shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────┬─────┬────────────┐
│ a         ┆ b   ┆ a.index(b) │
│ ---       ┆ --- ┆ ---        │
│ list[i64] ┆ i64 ┆ i64        │
╞═══════════╪═════╪════════════╡
│ [1, 2, 4] ┆ 3   ┆ null       │
│ [4, 4, 2] ┆ 4   ┆ 0          │
│ [6, 2, 7] ┆ 2   ┆ 1          │
└───────────┴─────┴────────────┘
```

Essentially this trades the `filter` for a `when.then.otherwise` and `groupby`. For the `groupby` to work we have to create a row index helper column at the beginning.

Comment: This is great. And thanks for multiple solutions!

Answer (score 2):

There is an [accepted feature request](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/5503) for `.list.index_of()` to be added to Polars.

As a workaround, you could manually flatten the lists and use [`pl.arg_where()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.arg_where.html#polars-arg-where) over each row.

```py
(df.with_row_index()
   .with_columns(
      pl.arg_where(pl.col("a").flatten() == pl.col("b"))
        .over("index")
        .alias("a.index(b)")
   )
)
```

```py
shape: (3, 4)
┌───────┬───────────┬─────┬────────────┐
│ index ┆ a         ┆ b   ┆ a.index(b) │
│ ---   ┆ ---       ┆ --- ┆ ---        │
│ u32   ┆ list[i64] ┆ i64 ┆ u32        │
╞═══════╪═══════════╪═════╪════════════╡
│ 0     ┆ [1, 2, 3] ┆ 3   ┆ 2          │
│ 1     ┆ [4, 5, 2] ┆ 4   ┆ 0          │
│ 2     ┆ [6, 2, 7] ┆ 2   ┆ 1          │
└───────┴───────────┴─────┴────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

This works but not sure how it scales performance-wise. I tried `arr.eval` but can't refer to another column in there, I tried exploding within one expression to use `pl.arg_where` or the like but couldn't figure out height mismatches, etc.

My answer makes a separate DataFrame with the answer by generating a row-count to do an eventual `over` expression and an `explode` of the DataFrame, so a `with_context` is needed overall (it's faster than a `concat`):

```py
df.lazy().with_context(
    df.lazy()
    .with_row_count()
    .explode("a")
    .select(c=pl.arg_where(pl.col("a") == pl.col("b")).over("row_nr"))
).select("a", "b", "c").collect()
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a         ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ ---       ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ list[i64] ┆ i64 ┆ u32 │
╞═══════════╪═════╪═════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] ┆ 3   ┆ 2   │
│ [4, 5, 2] ┆ 4   ┆ 0   │
│ [6, 2, 7] ┆ 2   ┆ 1   │
└───────────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Open to improvements!